# PowerPoint Programmatically find and delete animation/effect

Tags: vba, animation, vsto, powerpoint

I have programmatically (VSTO) added animations to the PowerPoint slide using the following code

```
    activeSlide.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add().AddTriggerEffect(
        textBox2,
        MsoAnimEffect.msoAnimEffectFade,
        MsoAnimTriggerType.msoAnimTriggerOnMediaBookmark,
        selectedShape,
        "Bookmark A",
        MsoAnimateByLevel.msoAnimateLevelNone);   

    activeSlide.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Add().AddTriggerEffect(
        textBox2,
        MsoAnimEffect.msoAnimEffectFade,
        MsoAnimTriggerType.msoAnimTriggerOnMediaBookmark,
        selectedShape,
        "Bookmark B",
        MsoAnimateByLevel.msoAnimateLevelNone).Exit = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
```

So how would I go about deleting the animation without deleting `textBox2`? Is there a way to traverse through the animations and find the ones I need to delete which are associated with `textBox2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Shyam Pillai for the answer, I translated his vba code as follows:

```
    private void DeleteAnnimations(Slide slide, Shape shape)
    {
        for (int i = slide.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences.Count; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            Sequence sequence = slide.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences[i];
            for (int x = sequence.Count; x >= 1; x--)
            {
                Effect effect = sequence[x];
                if (effect.Timing.TriggerType == MsoAnimTriggerType.msoAnimTriggerOnMediaBookmark)
                {
                    if (effect.Shape.Name == shape.Name)
                        effect.Delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me because I don't have PPT 2010 handy (you should note in your question it is that version) but this should get you started in the right direction.

`InteractiveSequences` is a collection of `Sequence` objects
`Sequence` object is really a collection of `Effect` objects
`Effect` objects have a `Shape` property

```
foreach (Sequence seq in activeSlide.TimeLine.InteractiveSequences)
  foreach (Effect eff in seq)
    if (eff.Shape == "target shape")
      ...
```

I believe there is a remove or maybe a delete function for the Effect object itself.

Comment: You cant foreach the office objects and then delete, so I found out of experience.  You have to for loop

Answer (score 0):

it's simply deleting the animation without deleting textbox:

```
dim osh as shape

set osh = .....

oSh.AnimationSettings.Animate = 0 => deleting the animation of osh
```